# Deriving relationship between distance and angle for field of a line charge

Tags: electrostatics, geometry

The relationship $r\,\mathrm{d}\alpha = \mathrm{d}x \cos(\alpha)$ is not obvious to me. In fact, when I look at it, I think it should be $r\,\mathrm{d}\alpha \cos(\alpha) = \mathrm{d}x$. Can someone explain where this relationship is coming from?

Eventually the goal is to find the electric field at P given the line with total charge $Q$, but I think that part will be fine when I understand what they are saying here.

[image: line charge with a point]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your picture, with a couple of additional angles and segments drawn:

[image]

Do you see it now?

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$\tan \alpha=\frac{a-x}{b}\implies\sec^2 \alpha \,d\alpha=-\frac{dx}{b}\implies\frac{r^2}{b^2}d\alpha=-\frac{dx}{b}\implies rd\alpha=-\cos\alpha\,dx,$$
which is the desired relation with a minus sign, that must be present, since an increase of $x$ decreases $\alpha$.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps looking at it like this will help clarify things:

[image: enhanced diagram of line charge]

You have two triangles, one with angle $\alpha$ and one with angle $\alpha + \mathrm{d}\alpha$. The sides opposite those angles differ by $\mathrm{d}x$, but the hypotenuses are essentially the same, both equal to $r$.

Write an equation expressing the fact that the triangles' opposite sides differ by $\mathrm{d}x$, and between that and some trigonometry, you should be able to get the relation given.

Comment: Is it correct to say $x = r\sin\alpha$ and $x + dx = r\sin(\alpha + d\alpha)$ ?

Comment: Try drawing out this diagram for yourself, labeling $x$, and see if it is in the right place to satisfy those equations.

Comment: Ok let me try again: is it correct to say $a-x = r\sin\alpha$ and $a-x + dx = r\sin(\alpha + d\alpha)$ ?

Comment: I can also write it in terms of $\tan$ and now I do understand the method that Mateus gave. Is this what you were thinking? I still want to see it in terms of dx and d$\alpha$ without needing the derivative of $\tan$ if that makes sense, just curiosity

Comment: (2 comments up) is there a reason you think that wouldn't be correct? ;-) (1 comment up) there are several different ways to get that relationship. Starting from the tangent, as Mateus did, is one, but what I've shown you in the image is a different way.

Comment: I think what I wrote was correct, although I don't see an obvious way to simplify it. Even with the relationship I still don't get my instructor's solution. Not sure if I should open a separate question for this.

Comment: Please see the revised question, I am actually pulling my hair out trying to understand the instructor's solution. I appreciate your help so far!

Comment: @Henry yes, I would say you should roll back your last edit to the question and ask a new question about any other concepts you don't understand.